# Calendar Dialog is opening twice

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-calendar, 2019

Sometimes it happens that when I create a new calendar item, a dialog box pops up twice.

[image]

[image]
Does anyone have an idea how to solve this problem?

Thanks,

necik.

Answer (score 0):

Have you add some code in this calendar list?

Try to create a new calendar list and compare whether the issue exists in the new list.

Try to create a

Comment: I have a lot of my custom code there, but to be sure I created a new calendar without a custom code and it behaves exactly the same.
Is it possible that it is SHP 2019? And sometimes it happens that I got shadow overlay( class ms-dlgOverlay) and I must refresh the page.